# Python sum of elements

Tags: python

Can some one explain me this code? I can't understand why sumOfLetter for i in inputText for sumOfLetter. What does second "for" do?

```
sum([sumOfLetter for i in inputText for sumOfLetter, weigthOfCh in pointsInRu.items() if i in weigthOfCh])
```

I find this code for my solution, changed variable names and it's work correct, but don't understand how it works.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code-explaining service. Please see [ask]

Answer (score 1):

This notation is shorthand for the code below. The square brackets show there's a `list` being created and directly used for the `sum()` function. Since the list is created and directly used, there's no variable and also no `append()` (this is done implicitely).

```py
new_list = []
for i in inputText:
  for sumOfLetter, weigthOfCh in pointsInRu.items():
    if i in weigthOfCh:
      new_list.append(sumOfLetter)

sum(new_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a python expert, but i think this is what is going on:

`pointsInRu` is a key-value pair (dictionary might be what it is called) that contains letters as keys.

`inputText` self explanatory.

`[sumOfLetter for i in inputText for sumOfLetter, weigthOfCh in pointsInRu.items() if i in weigthOfCh]` is where things get sketchy, its a list comprehension that iterates over each character i in inputText, and for each character, it checks if it exists in the keys of `pointsInRu`. If it does, then it extracts the corresponding value `weigthOfCh` and appends it to a list called `sumOfLetter`.

Then the sum() function is used to sum up all the values in the sumOfLetter list and return the total value.

Answer (score 0):

To be fair, this is pretty nasty code, let's give it a go:

1. The original code:

```py
sum([sumOfLetter for i in inputText for sumOfLetter, weigthOfCh in pointsInRu.items() if i in weigthOfCh])
```

2. The above is equivalent to this:

```py
my_values = [sumOfLetter for i in inputText 
            for sumOfLetter, weigthOfCh in pointsInRu.items() 
            if i in weigthOfCh]

sum(my_values)
```

To go further I'll make some assumptions,

`inputText` is some fixed string
`pointsInRu` is a dictionary mapping a number to a string (?)

Then:

```py
my_values = [sumOfLetter for i in inputText 
            for sumOfLetter, weigthOfCh in pointsInRu.items() 
            if i in weigthOfCh]
```

is equivalent to:

```py
my_values  = []

for i in inputText:
   for sumOfLetter, weigthOfCh in pointsInRu.items():
      if i in weigthOfCh:
          my_values.append(sumOfLetter)
```

This code illustrates the syntax that is being used:

```py
[f'{i=}{j=}' for i in [1,2,3] for j in [5,6,7]]

>>> [
 'i=1j=5',
 'i=1j=6',
 'i=1j=7',
 'i=2j=5',
 'i=2j=6',
 'i=2j=7',
 'i=3j=5',
 'i=3j=6',
 'i=3j=7']
```